# Convergence of a recursive sequence $u_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

This is my question.
Let the sequence $u_n$ be recursively defined by $u_{n+1} = \frac{k}{1+u_n}$ where k>0 and $u_1$>0. Check the convergence of the sequence.

So I used this method.

Since $u_1$>0 and k>0 for all n $\epsilon$ $Z_+$,$u_n$>0

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} u_{n+1} = \frac{k}{1 + \lim_{n\to \infty} u_n}$$
Suppose $\lim_{n\to \infty} u_n$ exist and $\lim_{n\to \infty} u_n = t$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty} u_{n+1} = t$

$$t = \frac{k}{1+t}$$
$$t^2 + t - k = 0$$
$$t = \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4k}}{2}$$
Since $u_1$>0 and k>0 for all n $\epsilon$ $Z_+$,$u_n$>0

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} u_n = \frac{\sqrt{1+4k}-1}{2}$$
Therefore the sequence is convergent

I'm not really sure this is the write way to do this. Please help me. If there is a better way please mention it.

Comment: To prove that a sequence is convergent you cannot start assuming that it is convergent.

Comment: So what would be the best way to approach this question then

Comment: Your argument needs two parts.  One part, which you did, shows **if** it is convergent, then the limit is what you computed.  The other part needs to show that it converges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some thoughts:

First of all, the sequence is bounded:

\begin{align*}
u_{n} = \frac{k}{1+u_{n-1}} = \frac{k}{1+\frac{k}{1+u_{n-2}}} = \frac{(1+u_{n-2}) \cdot k}{1+u_{n-2} + k} < \frac{(1+u_{n-2}) \cdot k}{1+u_{n-2}} = k.
\end{align*}
Also, it is oscillating in the sense that $u_n < u_{n+1} \Leftrightarrow u_{n+1} > u_{n+2}$: If, for instance, $u_{n} < u_{n+1}$, then
\begin{align*}
u_{n+2} = \frac{k}{1+u_{n+1}} < \frac{k}{1+u_n} = u_{n+1},
\end{align*}
and vice versa. Using this oscillating property, one can prove that $|u_{n+1} - u_n | < |u_{n}- u_{n-1}|$ for all $n$, and with some estimates of the size of $|u_{n+1}-u_n|$ one can then hope to prove that

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |u_{n+1}-u_n| = 0.
\end{align*}

This will force the sequence to zoom in on some real point, which will of course be the limit.

Comment: I am stucked at proving $|u_{n+1} - u_n | < |u_{n}- u_{n-1}|$. Can you please elaborate your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You have proven that if the limit exists, it is $\sqrt{k+\frac14}-\frac12$. However, you have not proven that the limit exists.

---

Suppose that
$$
u_{n+1}=\frac{k}{1+u_n}\tag1
$$
Since $k\gt0$, if $u_n\gt0$, then $u_{n+1}\gt0$.

Adding $1$ to $(1)$ and multiplying by $1+u_n$ yields
$$
(1+u_n)(1+u_{n+1})=k+1+u_n\tag2
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
u_{n+1}-u_n
&=\frac{k}{1+u_n}-\frac{k}{1+u_{n-1}}\tag3\\
&=\frac{k(u_{n-1}-u_n)}{(1+u_n)(1+u_{n-1})}\tag4\\
&=\frac{k(u_{n-1}-u_n)}{k+1+u_{n-1}}\tag5\\
&=-(u_n-u_{n-1})\,\frac{k}{k+1+u_{n-1}}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(3)$: apply $(1)$
$(4)$: subtract fractions
$(5)$: apply $(2)$
$(6)$: rearrange factors

Thus,
$$
|u_{n+1}-u_n|\le|u_n-u_{n-1}|\frac{k}{k+1}\tag7
$$
Since $\frac{k}{k+1}\lt1$, we can compute the following sum, which, because of $(7)$, is bounded by a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with ratio $\frac{k}{k+1}$:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty|u_{n+1}-u_n|\le\overbrace{\,(k+1)\,}^{\frac1{1-\frac{k}{k+1}}}\overbrace{|u_2-u_1|}^{\text{first term}}\tag8
$$
Since the left hand side of $(8)$ converges, the sequence converges to
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=u_1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(u_{n+1}-u_n)\tag9
$$

Comment: I understand up to $(7)$. But after that how did you get $(8)$ and prove the convergence ?

Comment: @Nimantha: I have expanded the explanation. Let me know if there is still anything unclear.